# Why doesn't scraping via class name work in this example?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the table from the url, but I can only scrape
it via `id` and not `class`, though there is only one such class.
Is there something wrong with my format? 
I have tried `find` or `find_all` and similar variants but I can't seem
to figure out why I get back an empty `list` or None.

```
 url = 'https://www.us-proxy.org/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
table  =soup.find("table" , { "class" : "table table-striped table-bordered dataTable"} )
```

Here is the part I am trying to scrape

`class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try an array for the classes?

`soup.find('table', {'class':['table','table-striped','table-bordered','dataTable']}`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select the table, because class `dataTable` is added dynamically by Javascript. For selecting tags I would use CSS selectors, this script select the table you wants:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.us-proxy.org/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

print(soup.select('table.table.table-striped.table-bordered'))
```

Prints:

```
[<table cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="proxylisttable" width="100%"><thead><tr><th>IP Address</th><th>Port</th><th>Code</th><th class="hm">Country</th><th>Anonymity</th><th class="hm">Google</th><th class="hx">Https</th><th class="hm">Last Checked</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>47.90.246.198</td><td>3128</td><td>US</td><td class="hm">United States</td><td>elite proxy</td><td class="hm">no</td>
```

... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Comments re class have been made. Look at the return HTML: There is an id which should be your preferred method for selecting as is quicker and more likely unique

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.us-proxy.org/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('#proxylisttable')
table = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(table)
```